# Show difference between two tables in mysql using join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in my database: projects e invoices

**Table invoices**

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO `invoices` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Invoice 1'),
(2, 'Invoice 2'),
(3, 'Invoice 3');
```

**Table projects**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Fazendo dump de dados para tabela `projects`
--

INSERT INTO `projects` (`id`, `invoice_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Project name');
```

Expected result:
show rows

```
(2, 'Invoice 2'),
(3, 'Invoice 3')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want invoices where no project has that invoice, then one method uses `not exists`:

```
select i.*
from invoices i
where not exists (select 1
                  from projects p
                  where p.invoice_id = i.id
                 );
```